# Filling numpy arrays slower than for loop (h.fill vs h.fill.numpy)

Tags: histogrammar

It looks like filling a histogram with `.fill` is faster than filling with `.fill.numpy`.
For both cases my data is in a namedtuple:

```
Event = namedtuple("Event", ['nHGPulses', 'HGs1',
                             'HGs2', 'nHGs1', 'nHGs2', 'area_phd', 'width'])
```

and the histogram I am trying to fill is

```
h2_areawidth_pulses = hg.Bin(100, 0, 500, lambda x: x[0], hg.Bin(1000, 0, 5000, lambda x: x[1]))
for event in events:
    for a, w in zip(event.area_phd, event.width):
        h2_areawidth_pulses.fill((a, w))
```

or for the numpy case

```
h2_areawidth_pulses = hg.Bin(100, 0, 500, lambda event: event.area_phd, hg.Bin(1000, 0, 5000, lambda event: event.width))
for event in events:
    h2_areawidth_pulses.fill.numpy(event)
```

Under identical conditions `.fill` runs in 10s while `.fill.numpy` takes 195s.

Am I doing something wrong or is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen in cases with large numbers of bins. In Histogrammar's Numpy filling, the data to be sent to each bin is separately masked: with 100 bins, you run over the data 100 times. (That's not the case for the jit-compiled algorithms, such as cling and cuda.)

The culprit for this bad algorithm is Histogrammar's generality— at that level of structure, I don't know what's below it, so I have to provide separate inputs to each bin.

This is not the case for histbook, Histogrammar's successor. Now that I've added SparkSQL-filling to histbook, it may satisfy your needs. When it's a complete replacement, I'll put a redirect on Histogrammar's homepage, but for now, I've been speaking the word however I can.

Comment: Thanks, I've found histbook a while ago, but could not figure out how to do 2D plots :)

Comment: I'll take that as a second request for 2D plots. The quickest way would probably be to export to TH2, since I haven't investigated Vega-Lite's 2D plotting yet (if it even has it). I need to run find the appropriate `NotImplementedError` stub in histbook/external.py and fill it out.